# A word to describe what a company does when it adds balance to a credit account due to interest

Tags: single-word-requests, finance

So I have a debt of $500. After a month, I owe $600 because my debtor has added to my account due to interest (also because the account has a terrible APR). In this situation I would say my creditor has (1._________). I would also say interest has been (2.______) against my account

I could swear I've read this word in context, I just can't for the life of me remember it.

Comment: _negative amortization_

Comment: Are you looking for _debited_? Or simply _charged_? Interest has _accrued,_ but the debtor hasn't accrued, and it hasn't accrued _against_ anything.

Comment: There really isn't any word, except to say that the creditor has *added interest to the account*.

Comment: Or are you looking for _levied_?

Answer (score 1):

For #1, I can't think of a *single* word that would fit there. It would mostly require at least two words, including a direct object (probably "me" or "my account").

For #2, interest accrues, but when it gets added to your amount owed, it becomes **capitalized**.

https://myfedloan.org/help-center/faq/interest-faq.shtml

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found the word I was looking for. Using the third definition [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/assess)

I might say my creditor has ***assessed*** interest.

I might also say interest has been ***assessed*** against my account.

From Dictionary.Com

### Assess

verb (used with object)

1. to estimate officially the value of (property, income, etc.) as a basis for taxation.
2. to fix or determine the amount of (damages, a tax, a fine, etc.):The hurricane damage was assessed at six million dollars.
3. to impose a tax or other charge on.
4. to estimate or judge the value, character, etc., of; evaluate:to assess one's efforts.

Comment: I don't think that "assess" is the correct term for the context you are describing.